# New Google Images .htaccess redirect code

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How do I make redirects in htaccess for traffic comming from "new" google images (google.com/images), instead of the old one (images.google.com) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://google.com/images [NC]
RewriteRule .* new-redirect-url [NC,L]
```

Optionally, you can append R=301 to RewriteRule flags if you wish to do 301 redirect, like: `NC,L,R=301`.

Also, adjust referer URL if needed, this is sort of generic solution.